# Deploy nodejs with auto scaling and AWS load balancer

Tags: node.js, amazon-elb

I have a nodejs app that I can run on an ec2. 
I run it with node app.js.it listens to 80
Now I want to use ELB for autosclaing. But I dont know how to setup health check. 
I created the target group and both ec2 instances are running healthy but I get 503.
Also, if it wants to scale out, what will happen to the application as it cannot get copied to the other instance. Only AMI gets copied.
I know the question  is simple but I havent used auto scaling before.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autoscaling group and AWS Codedeploy to achieve this. Although I recommend using ECS and ECS Fargate (Container solutions), one thing you should think about is using this AMI to serve as a starting point, and then use AWS codedeploy to pull the latest code, and run it.

Moreover, concerning the 503 Error, how are you starting your nodeJS server and guarantee that it is always running? 503 means that the health checks failed and that the target group contains no healthy targets. Two think you should check:
- Is the nodeJS server running inside the machine always?
- A health check is as simple as a GET request that returns any response with a status code 200.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user-data section to add commands for pull code from github and start the app. here is a youtube tutorial video that has detailed steps on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB3Ip0Yn-Zs